# Use ANT to update build number and inject into source code

Tags: ant, build-process

In my build.xml file I am incrementing a build version number in a property file like so:

```
<target name="minor">
     <propertyfile file="build_info.properties">
         <entry key="build.minor.number" type="int" operation="+" value="1" pattern="00" />
         <entry key="build.revision.number" type="int" value="0" pattern="00" />
     </propertyfile>
</target>
```

I also have similar entries for the major and revision. (from [Build numbers: major.minor.revision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431315/build-numbers-major-minor-revision))

This works great. Now I would like to take this incremented build number and inject it into my source code:

```
    //Main.as
    public static const VERSION:String = "@(#)00.00.00)@";
```

By using:

```
<target name="documentVersion">
    <replaceregexp file="${referer}" match="@\(#\).*@" replace="@(#)${build.major.number}.${build.minor.number}.${build.revision.number})@" />
</target>
```

Now this sorta works. It does indeed replace the version *but* with the outdated version number. So whenever I run the ANT script the build_info.properties is updated to the correct version but my source code file is using the pre updated value.

I have echoed to check that indeed I am incrementing the build number before I call the replace and I have noticed that echoing:

```
<echo>${build.minor.number}</echo> 
//After updating it still shows old non updated value here but the new value in the property file.
```

So is there a way to retrieve the updated value in the property file so I can use it to inject into my source code?

Cheers

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/690419/build-and-version-numbering-for-java-projects-ant-cvs-hudson

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So after spending hours not being able to solve this, I post this question and then figure it out 20 minutes later.

The problem was I had this at the top of my build file:

```
<property file="build_info.properties"/>
```

I guess it was due to scoping and that properties are immutable thus I was never able to update the value. Removing that line and then adding the following got it working perfectly:

```
<target name="injectVersion">
     <property file="build_info.properties"/>
     <replaceregexp file="${referer}" match="@\(#\).*@" replace="@(#)${build.major.number}.${build.minor.number}.${build.revision.number})@" />
</target>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use `<buildnumber/>`?

Answer (score 0):

```
 Project used to increment build number in build.properties file

 file parameters:
 version.number=                
 build.number=        

 if changes version.number then build.number starts from 1                                                      
 ====================================================================== -->
```

```
<property name="versionFileName" value="build.properties" />
<property file="${versionFileName}" />  
<property name="currentVersion" value="0.1.37"/>

<target name="calculate.version.build">
    <script language="javascript">
        <![CDATA[             
            var currentVersion = project.getProperty("currentVersion");
            var oldVersion = project.getProperty("version.number");
            var buildNumber = project.getProperty("build.number");

            if (!currentVersion.equals(oldVersion)){
                project.setProperty("currentBuild", 1);
            } else {
                var newBuildNumber = ++buildNumber;
                project.setProperty("currentBuild", newBuildNumber);
            }
        ]]> 
    </script>
</target>

<target name="update.version.build" depends="calculate.version.build">
    <propertyfile file="${versionFileName}">
        <entry key="build.number" type="int" operation="=" value="${currentBuild}" />
        <entry key="version.number" type="string" operation="=" value="${currentVersion}" />
    </propertyfile>
    <echo message="New version: ${currentVersion}.${currentBuild}" />
</target>
```

Comment: You should provide some explanation, not only cut'n'paste code as an answer, to reach a good quality answer.